How to Set Up Step Execution with Custom Retries in Acidic Jobs (Rails)
I'm transitioning from using Sidekiq to Acidic Jobs in my Rails application. I'm relatively new to Acidic Jobs and would appreciate some guidance on setting up step execution for my jobs.
Specifically, I'm looking to configure custom retry logic for different jobs. In Sidekiq, I could easily define the number of retries for each job, but I'm unsure how to achieve this in Acidic Jobs. For example, I want certain jobs to have 2 retries and others to have 3 retries.
Could someone guide me on how to implement this in Acidic Jobs? Any code examples or documentation references would be greatly appreciated!
